# How do I deduce my latitude and longitude from N obervations of occultations from the same place?

Tags: the-moon, amateur-observing

I think it would be an interesting exercise to measure the latiude and longitude of my house using N occultation timings. I would like to see how precisely I can measure it using that technique, and compare it with the GPS readings from my phone.

I'm looking for a reference which will tell me how to do the calculation of inferring my position from occultation timings, as accurately as possible.

Comment: Latitude can be easily derived from the Sun and will be needed for calculating longitude. The American practical navigator 1861 (google play) gives a method but I can't follow it. Information on this is hard to find but I hope to sort it out soon.
Bob

Comment: http://occultations.org/ if you're watching for asteroid occultations. If you're only using moon/planet/star occultations, those are less frequent. You could try using Stellarium and alter the latitude until it matches the occultation you see in the sky?